# Could the "7 Thunders" be in reference to the "7 Bowls" of God's wrath, which are heralded by way of the "7th Trumpet"? Rev, 10:3,4

Tags: john, revelation, ezekiel, sevenfold

As John has already written about the first 6 trumpet blasts, there can only be 1 more trumpet blast to come, which is to herald God's ultimate wrath, by way of the pouring out of the bowls of His wrath, which just happen to be 7 in number.

**Rev, 4:5 NASB**

> *And from the throne proceed flashes of lightning and sounds and **peals of thunder**. And there were **seven lamps of fire** burning before (God's) throne, which are the **seven spirits of God***.

Seven angels (spirits in themselves), before God's throne, are utilized to pour out God's *seven* bowls of wrath upon the earth, while flashes of lightning and sounds and **peals of thunder** abound, directly from the throne of God Himself.

**Ezek, 19:19 NASB**

> *When the sound of the **trumpet** grew louder and louder, Moses spoke and God answered him with **thunder**.*

If the "7 Thunders" being talked about in **Rev, 10:3,4**, after the 6th trumpet has already heralded its own cause and effect, are not in reference to the "7 Bowls" of God's wrath, then what could they possibly be in reference to??

Comment: I believe the book of Revelation is divided into seven parts, each addressing the same subject but from a different perspective

Comment: @Betho's - I thank you for the upvote but can't go along with your assertion. Having said that, the similarity between "trumpets" and "bowls" is unmistakable.

Answer (score 2):

"Thunder" [βροντή bronte] occurs 10 times in the book of Revelation 4:5, 6:1, 8:5, 10:3, 4, 11:19, 14:2, 16:18, 19:6. Thunder either represents the voice of God or accompanies His voice. In either case it signifies a Divine utterance. Comparison with the only other occurrence in the NT, Jn 12:29 (apart from the incidental Mk
3:17) lends weight to this view.

The OT usage is similar, eg, Job 26:14, 37:4, 1 Sam 2:10, Ps 29:3, Eze 19:19, etc.

The seven thunders are the only part of Revelation which was sealed - an allusion to the sealed book of Daniel (8:26, 12:4, 9).

The very fact that the seven thunders are sealed (Rev 10:4), means that their meaning remains hidden.  What the Lord has seen fit to hide must remain so.

Comment: *What the Lord has seen fit to hide must remain so*. Well, of course, that depends on where we have got to in God's timetable. This world could have already experienced one, or two, or more .... of the "thunders" in question.  Still, it was good to see all the verse references that include "thunder".